# Displaying filtered values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The problem asks that I Create a program that sorts all employees by last name and prints them to the screen in a tabular format. Implement the data using a list of maps. My problem is my console only displays all the elements in the array. The elements are sorted which is what I needed but I can not just print the names. Any ideas?

```
//global array of employee list
var users = [
    {firstname : "Jacquelyn", lastname: "Jackson",    position:"DBA",               separationDate:""},
    {firstname : "John",      lastname: "Johnson",    position:"Manager",           separationDate:"2016-12-31"},
    {firstname : "Sally",     lastname: "Weber",      position:"Web Developer",     separationDate:"2015-12-18"},
    {firstname : "Michaela",  lastname: "Michaelson", position:"District Manager",  separationDate:"2015-12-19"},
    {firstname : "Jake",      lastname: "Jacobson",   position:"Programmer",        separationDate:""},
    {firstname : "Tou",       lastname: "Xiong",      position:"Software Engineer", separationDate:"2016-10-05"}
];

//compare first name, puts array in order
 users.sort(function(a,b){
    return a.firstname.localeCompare(b.firstname);
});

console.log(users.sort());
```

Comment: How are you doing the "tabular format"? (The assignment is suspiciously unspecific)

Comment: tbh i didnt know what it ment by tabular format. I figured it wanted something printed out in a table. But I'm not how to do that in javascript. I know how to do it in php which is really easy to implement.

Comment: it's quite similar in JS, just that you don't print it (to the console) but output it to the DOM. Regardless - you just loop over your sorted array and put down the names.

Comment: *I can not just print the names.* What do you mean by "I can not"? Do you mean "I don't know how to"? You need to access a **property** (`firstname` etc.) on an **object**. Did you learn how to do that yet in your study? If not, go back and carefully re-read the materials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to loop and log for it to display each name:

```
users.forEach(u => console.log(u.firstname));
```

Comment: High Five! You hit the nail on the head. Question though what does the u stand for?

Comment: @WalterPurvis user

Comment: is that like a  local var?

Comment: @WalterPurvis it's a returned value from the forEach method. It sounds like you're new to the language, a great resource is MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @WalterPurvis It's a parameter name of the function, so yes it introduces a local variable.  Has nothing to do with `forEach` specifically - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @zfrish No, it's not a "returned value" from the `forEach` method. Let's help out the beginners by being precise in our terminology. "Return value" has a specific meaning. `u` here represents the **parameter** which `forEach` passes to its callback.